# python web server error handling

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, webserver

This is my python webserver code. But it doesn't work the error message as I wish. So, please, help me to correct to generate error message.

```
import sys
import http.server

from http.server import(
SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)

srvr=http.server.HTTPServer
hnd=SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

Protocol='HTTP/1.0'
try:
    if sys.argv[1:]:
        port=int(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        port=8000
    srvradrs=('localhost',port)
    hnd.protocol_version=Protocol
    h=srvr(srvradrs,hnd)
except IOError:
    self.send_error(404,'File Not Found please check again and enter correct flie name!!!!!!!!!: %s' %self.path)

print("It's worked and welcome for my web server!")
h.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

You use "self" in self.send_error, but you're not inside a method (member function) of any class c.q. object.